# Issue with Sublime Text Unity icon

Tags: unity, icons, sublime-text

I just installed Sublime Text 3 via the terminal from the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

I added the Sublime launcher to my Unity bar, however when I click on it, instead of activating that icon, a grey question mark icon appears in the buttom of the tray like so (it's partially cut off): https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0G6H.jpg. How do I fix this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and here's how I solved it:

Adding it via drag and drop from /usr/share/applications using nautilus was always giving me the duplicated unity launcher icons.

I launched the application from a terminal window and used the "Lock to launcher" right click option on its panel icon, which seemed to work as expected once I dropped into the launcher from nautilus.

The problem was the desktop file from /usr/share/applications has some extra features which the drag-and-drop-generated shortcut(located in ~/.local/share/applications) was missing, like "New Window" and "New file" right click menu options, which I didn't want to lose. So I tried to see what's different between them, and the only significant difference I could see was this attribute:

> StartupWMClass=Sublime_text

Once I added that to the .desktop file from /usr/share/applications it started working. I then deleted the generated shortcut from ~/.local/share/applications and it seems to work.

I hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the default icon like this

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/alecive/flatwoken/512/Apps-sublime-text-icon.png
$ gksu 'gedit /usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop'
```

change this line:

> Icon=sublime-text

to

> icon=~/Downloads/Apps-sublime-text-icon.png

save it